# Java Sound Background Noise Removal

Tags: java, sockets, audio, javasound, noise

Whenever I am using SourceDataLine class in Java to read the bytes that comprise of the audio, I am getting an annoying buzzing background noise on playback. Can anyone tell me how I could get rid of it altogether? Thanks in advance.

Update: I have posted the code, but my actual objective is to take the byte data from the microphone and transmit it to another client. I am placing the codes for the clients. The server is immaterial here since its only role is to forward the byte array to another client.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Client001 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton startButton = new JButton("Open Microphone");
    DataInputStream fromServer;
    DataOutputStream toServer;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, true);
    DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    TargetDataLine targetLine; 
    SourceDataLine sourceLine;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final Client001 c = new Client001();
        c.connect2Server();
        c.initializeSoundParams();
        c.initGUI();

        Thread receiver = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                c.startSoundReceiver();
            }

        };
        receiver.start();







    }

    public void connect2Server(){

        try{


            Socket socket = new Socket("108.61.181.112",8000);
            fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());



        }

        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void initializeSoundParams(){

        try{
            targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
            sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }


    public byte[] filterNoise(byte[] data,int range){

        byte value = data[0];
        for (int i=1; i<data.length; i++){
                byte currentValue = data[i];
                value += (currentValue - value) / range;
                data[i] = value;
        }

        return data;
    }



    public void startSoundReceiver(){

        try{

            toServer.writeUTF("1");
            sourceLine.open(format);
            sourceLine.start();

            while(true){

                int dataSize = fromServer.readInt();                        
                System.out.println("Length = " + dataSize);                 
                byte[] targetData = new byte[dataSize];
                fromServer.readFully(targetData,0,dataSize);
                //targetData = filterNoise(targetData,60);
                sourceLine.write(targetData, 0, targetData.length);
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public void startSoundSender(){


        try{

            targetLine.open(format);
            targetLine.start();

            int numBytesRead;
            byte[] targetData = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];

            //toServer.writeUTF("1");

            while (true) {
                numBytesRead = targetLine.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);

                System.out.println("Length = " + numBytesRead);

                if (numBytesRead == -1) break;

                toServer.writeInt(numBytesRead);
                toServer.write(targetData,0,numBytesRead);

                //sourceLine.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





    public void initGUI(){


        setLayout(null);
        startButton.setBounds(30, 30, 180, 70);
        add(startButton);
        setTitle("Sound GUI");
        setSize(300,300);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == startButton){
            Thread sender = new Thread(){
                public void run(){

                    startSoundSender();
                }

            };
            sender.start();


        }



    }




}


import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Client002 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton startButton = new JButton("Open Microphone");
    DataInputStream fromServer;
    DataOutputStream toServer;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 2, true, true);
    DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    TargetDataLine targetLine; 
    SourceDataLine sourceLine;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final Client002 c = new Client002();
        c.connect2Server();
        c.initializeSoundParams();
        c.initGUI();

        Thread receiver = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                c.startSoundReceiver();
            }

        };
        receiver.start();







    }

    public void connect2Server(){

        try{


            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.102",8000);
            fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());



        }

        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void initializeSoundParams(){

        try{
            targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
            sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    public byte[] filterNoise(byte[] data,int range){

        byte value = data[0];
        for (int i=1; i<data.length; i++){
                byte currentValue = data[i];
                value += (currentValue - value) / range;
                data[i] = value;
        }

        return data;
    }

    public void startSoundReceiver(){

        try{

            toServer.writeUTF("2");
            sourceLine.open(format);
            sourceLine.start();

            while(true){

                int dataSize = fromServer.readInt();                        
                System.out.println("Length = " + dataSize);                 
                byte[] targetData = new byte[dataSize];
                fromServer.readFully(targetData,0,dataSize);
                targetData = filterNoise(targetData,20);
                sourceLine.write(targetData, 0, targetData.length);
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public void startSoundSender(){


        try{

            targetLine.open(format);
            targetLine.start();

            int numBytesRead;
            byte[] targetData = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];

            //toServer.writeUTF("1");

            while (true) {
                numBytesRead = targetLine.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);

                System.out.println("Length = " + numBytesRead);

                if (numBytesRead == -1) break;

                toServer.writeInt(numBytesRead);
                toServer.write(targetData,0,numBytesRead);

                //sourceLine.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





    public void initGUI(){


        setLayout(null);
        startButton.setBounds(30, 30, 180, 70);
        add(startButton);
        setTitle("Sound GUI");
        setSize(300,300);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == startButton){
            Thread sender = new Thread(){
                public void run(){

                    startSoundSender();
                }

            };
            sender.start();


        }



    }




}
```

Comment: It's quite possible that the buzzing is coming from you improperly handling the data. Since you didn't post any code, we will never know.

Comment: @jaket Posted some code. Sorry for not doing so then

Comment: Kind of went overboard there. Can you give us the minimum amount of code that reproduces your problem? Also, have you tested/verified that the components, such as your filter, work cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

if your sample size is **16 bits " AudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, true);"**

Then, you can't make your filter with single bytes

You should try to use sample size of 8 bits, or trying to combine two bytes to make your filter operations.